# Show that $x_2 = 0$ without solving the linear system explicitly.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Given the following matrix equation:
$$Ax = B$$
where 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
6 & -9 & 31 & 5 & -2\\
3 & 20 & 42 & 2 & 0 \\
26 & 9 & 92 & 20 & -10 \\
1 & 2 & 81 & 4 & 22 \\
4 & -1 & 3 & 1 & -10
\end{pmatrix}, x = \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
x_4 \\
x_5
\end{pmatrix} \quad \text{and}\quad B= \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
5 \\
-11 \\
5
\end{pmatrix}.$$

> Question: If the linear system has a unique solution, show that $x_2 = 0$ without solving the linear system explicitly.

I have been puzzling on this problem for few days.

I attempted to solve the linear system but it is not allowed in this question.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Think of $Ax$ as a sum of columns then think about linear independence. You can find a (the) complete solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C$ denote the last column of $A$. Then we have

$$-\frac{1}{2}C=B.$$

This shows that $(0,0,0,0, -\frac{1}{2})^T$ is a solution of the system $Ax=B$.

Since the system has a unique solution, $(0,0,0,0, -\frac{1}{2})^T$ is this solution, hence $x_2=0.$

Comment: A hint was asked for?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Use Cramer's formula for $x_2$  (which supposes the determinaant of the linear system is not $0$).

Answer (score 2):

$x$ is a (unique) linear combination of the columns of $A$. $B$ and the last column of $A$ are linear dependent. Thus the unique solution must be in $\{(0,0,0,0,\lambda) | \lambda \in \mathbb R\}$.